# Ad Broken on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro, advertising

Visiting Stack Overflow today, [I found a broken ad](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/870352541921554437).  Here is its URL:

> https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjsi/ad.atdmt.com/81487/14358435/d/a.html;p=11087213718728;cod=1;idfa=;aaid=;idfa_lat=;aaid_lat=;cache=1496344010107?click=https%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fr%3Fe%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%26s%3DogIUSpPaGWAcFHMrdKX8huV1GhY%26url=
>   [image]

Comment: Looks like it is hiding behind ad blocker sensing code.  I was able to see the ad after disabling my ad blocker.  Also the link is kind of a give away `https://fw.adsafeprotected...`

Comment: I'm using Chrome, I wasn't aware I was using a ad blocker

Comment: Really can't seem to reproduce this error. Even tried turning an ad blocker on and it didn't fail. Safe to assume you're seeing it repeatedly, @GeorgeStocker?

Comment: @stevvve Yes.  It could very well by my corporate proxy; just never saw this before.

Comment: I'm not sure how you test @stevvve but if I click that link I get nothing. Is that expected? Or do those links only work when served within a stackoverflow.com domain?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker What's curious to me is that neither this advertiser nor this creative is new. So I'm trying to figure out what changed. We just started a new month so that *kind of* helps get closer to solving...

Comment: Possibly helpful context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355890/neterr-insecure-response-in-chrome

Comment: :-| @rene I click that link and the ad loads

Comment: @stevvve this is my devconsole on Chrome  for that ad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLd4P.png  maybe it is location related?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker This was back-burnered for a bit, and I'm checking back in now. Still seeing this stinker?

Comment: @stevvve haven't in a while. Unclear of what was going on.

Comment: @stevvve Around that same time we started having issues with our corporate firewall; so I'm going to chalk this up to that.

Comment: @rene still having the issue?

Comment: @Braiam I still get no ad served, assuming that is how you can describe the issue.